# Centraliser of regular semisimple element in $G^F$, for a connected reductive algebraic group $G$

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, lie-theory

Let $G$ be an connected reductive algebraic group over $k=\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$. Suppose $G$ is defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $G^{F}$ be the corresponding finite group associated to $G$. Suppose $s\in G^{F}$ is a regular semisimple element. Now, $s$ is contained in a unique maximal Torus $T$, and $T$ is necessarily $F$-stable. Let $T^F$ denote the set of $F$-rational points of $T$.

It is clear that $T^F\subseteq C_{G^F}(s)$. My question is whether $T^F=C_{G^F}(s)$? In the case that this isn’t true is there a simple description of the quantity $C_{G^F}(s)$?

Thank you.

Comment: You need a definition of a regular semisimple element. I think that a semisimple element $s$ of $G$ is called regular if its centralizer in $G$ is a (maximal) torus. Then in your case the centralizer of $s$ in $G$ is $T$, and hence, the centralizer of $s$ in $G^F$ is $T^F$.

Comment: Two comments: 1) See Chapter 3 in the 1985 book of R.W. Carter.or the long article by Springer-Steinberg in Lecture Notes in Mathematis 131 (1970). 2) This question has considerable overlap with a recent question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332689/

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi the definition of regular element is that $x$ will be called regular if dim($C_{G}(x))$ is minimal. Since, it is known that dim($C_{G}(x)) \geq rank(G)$, it turns out that $x$ is regular if dim($C_{G}(x))$ is equal to $rank(G)$. Now, since my consideration is $x$ is regular semisimple element, it is clear that $C_{G}(x)^{\circ}=T$, where $T$ is the unique maximal torus containing $x$.

Comment: Moreover, it is known that $[G,G]$ is simply connected then the centraliser of a semisimple element is connected, in which case your claim that $C_{G}(x)=T$, holds, and my claim holds.

Comment: My question now is that what happen if $[G,G]$ is not simply connected. Is the claim of the question still holds true?

Comment: @JimHumphreys, I have been following the references that you have given, but I couldn’t find a exact answer to my question there. Maybe I have missed something. As far as the reference to the math overflow question, that question was also asked by me, but I don’t seem to find much of resemblence, of this question to that! Again may be, I am missing something.

Comment: @Riju:  Your two questions are related but not the same.    I'm sorry if I implied the reverse.    I'm also sorry for oversimpllifying the questions too much.   (By trhe way, simply connected makes little difference to the question.)   Is there a reason to concentrate just on *regular* semisimple elements?

Comment: @JimHumphreys: Simply connectedness does make a difference, see my answer.

Comment: @JimHumphreys Probably the fact that if $s$ is regular, semisimple then $C_{G}(s)^{\circ}=T$, made me believe that the conclusion in the question has more possibility to hold than just a semisimple element.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332872/centraliser-of-regular-semisimple-element-in-gf-for-a-connected-reductive-al#comment830719_332872), isn't that usually called *strongly* regular semisimple (whereas just rss, as [@‍Riju](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332872/centraliser-of-regular-semisimple-element-in-gf-for-a-connected-reductive-al#comment830896_332872) says and [your answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/332993) does, usually drops the connectedness hypothesis)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good question! The answer is NO, see the counter-example below.

Take $p=3$; then $\mathbb F_3=\{0,1,-1\}$.
Write $L=\mathbb F_3(i)$, where $i^2=-1$; then $L\simeq \mathbb F_9$.

Take $$G={\rm GL}_{2,L}\,,\quad G'=G/\{\pm 1\}.$$
Let $T\subset G$ denote the subgroup of diagonal matrices.
Take 
$$ s={\rm diag}(i,-i)\in T(L)\subset G(L).$$
Then the centralizer of $s$ in $G$ is $T$, hence $s$ is a regular semisimple element of $G(L)$.

Write 
$$
n=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\in G(L).
$$
Then
$$ n s n^{-1} ={\rm diag}(-i,i)= -s.$$
This means that if we denote by $s'$ and $n'$ 
the images in $G'(L)$ of $s$ and $n$, respectively, then
$$ n' s' (n')^{-1} = s'.$$
Thus 
$$ n'\in C_{G'}(s')(L),$$
but $n'\notin T'(L)$, where $T'$ denotes the image of $T$ in $G'$.
We see that  $$C_{G'(L)}(s')\supsetneqq T'(L).$$
In the notation of the question, we obtain that 
$$C_{G^{\prime F}}(s')\supsetneqq T^{\prime F}.$$

Comment: Fine example! Btw is there any way to find a description of this quantity $C_{G^F}(s)$, in terms of $T^F$ and something more, just like we have a description of $C_{G}(s)$ , which says that it is generated by $T$ and “certain” root subgroups!

Comment: @Riju: A standard approach is first to compute $C_G(s)$, and after that to compute the set of  $L$-points $C_{G^F}(s)$ using Galois cohomology (which is not difficult  over a finite field $L$).

Comment: Namely, write $N=N_G(T)$, $W=N/T$. Then $C_G(s)\subset N$. For any $w=nT\in W$ we can define $wsw^{-1}$, and for a given regular semisimple element $s$ you have to compute the centralizer $C_W(s)$.

Comment: Now if $w=nT$ and $wsw^{-1}=s$, and moreover $w\in W^F$, then by Lang's theorem there exists $n_0\in N^F$ such that $w=n_0 T$. Clearly, $n_0\in C_{G^F}(s)$.

Comment: @Riju, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/831033), $C_G(s)$ is *not* always generated by $T$ and certain root groups; those are both connected, so we can only access $C_G(s)^\circ$ that way.  As @‍MikhailBorovoi's comments [1](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/831424) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/831425) indicate, $C_G(s)$ will generally fail to be connected (although it is so for $G$ simply connected!), and the failure is measured, algebraically (for any field) and rationally (for any finite field), by a quotient of $C_W(s)$.